# GNU Assembler .print expression instead of string

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler, preprocessor-directive

According this *https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Print.html#Print*, I only can print string instead of expression.

I tried this one line assembler

```
.print "Hello" //No Error
.print 1+2 //Error: missing string
```

How do I make assembler recognize that expression `1+2` is a string? I expect it will print:

```
Hello
3
```

UPDATE: I found something strange after using `.altmacro` https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html#Altmacro

```
.altmacro

.macro myMacro
  LOCAL myLabel
  .set myLabel, 1+2
  .print "myLabel"
.endm

myMacro
```

It said I can use `%expr`:
*You can write ‘%expr’ to evaluate the expression expr and use the result as a string.*

But my console shown:

```
.LL0001
```

Comment: @Koladez it's GNU Assembler (GAS) ```as``` in shell command.

Comment: The documentation you linked seems pretty clear: "`as` will print *string* on the standard output during assembly. You must put *string* in double quotes."  I guess you mean you *want* it to print `3`, not that you *expect* it?  Because it's pretty clear why `.print 1+2` doesn't work, there isn't a double-quoted string operand.  So the question is whether you can stringify a number with GAS macro processing, like CPP's `#define stringify(x) #x`

Comment: @PeterCordes I found something strange, look it up. I update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your both refference:

- Enable `.altmacro` which has more feature than legacy `as` such as LOCAL labeling.
- Define macro with name `.printPlusPlus`, name inspired from C++ that upgraded version of C but this context is version of `.print`
- Since `.print` only accept double quote string then put the parameter `a` to the double-quoted argument.
- Use pair of angle bracket `<my string>` for print string, use `%(expr)` to print string expression. Note, you must use escaped character hexadecimal to use hell character like double-quoted. `\x22` means **Character number 22 in hexadecimal form in ascii table** which it's a `"`.

## Usage

```
.altmacro

.macro .printPlusPlus a
  .print "\a"
.endm

.printPlusPlus <\x22\Hello World\x22>
.printPlusPlus %(1 +2)
```

## Output

```
$ as temp.m
"Hello World"
3
```

## EDIT

```
.altmacro

.macro .printPlusPlus a
  .print "\a"
.endm

.macro summation a,b
  .printPlusPlus %(\a + \b)
.endm

summation 3,4 //will show 7, i just tested it works fine
```

Comment: Can you generate the `%(expression)` with a macro, e.g. to make a macro that takes 2 separate args, and prints their sum?  e.g. with another macro that uses `printPlusPlus %(\a + \b)`?

Comment: What you mean with ```\a``` and with ```\b```. Are they parameter or macro?

Comment: Do you mean like this ```printPlusPlus 1 ,2``` that will print ```3``` to the stdout.

Comment: I mean if you have `.macro foo a, b`, can it expand it `.print %(\a + \b)`, or pass them to another macro like `bar %(\a + \b)` to do math on things that weren't originally inside a `%()` in the source?

Comment: Do you mean call a macro inside a defining another macro?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm typical person hardly understand when explanation in general or abstract. Means if you tell me the example what you expect from your explanation it will be easier for me to understand (maybe).

Comment: See my  edited answer part, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought was interesting, to see if one could do it with arbitrary inputs.

Comment: Seems my answer has weakness, how do you print ```"bool"``` with double quoted mark? ```.printPlusPlus <\x22bool\x22>``` it's print but not what I expect.

Comment: The answer is ```<\x22\x62ool\x22>```. Yeah so hell.